# What international postage agreement requires national carriers to use merely other national carriers?

Tags: postal-system

Whenever I do not care about shipping speed or times, I use national carriers to save money. Can anyone source or reference [the quotation below](https://www.reddit.com/r/PersonalFinanceCanada/comments/eoauog/is_there_any_way_to_avoid_paying_customs/fecho0w/)? Which "international postage agreements"?

> Private courtiers (DHL, UPS, etc) will always charge the duty because they collect a big fat brokerage fee from you. That's were you see the $50 charge on a $100 package.
>
> Canada Post only charges a flat $9.99 on brokerage no matter the value of the package so I prefer to ship via national carriers (Royal Mail, USPS, Japan Post, etc) which becomes a Canada Post package due to **international postage agreements [my emphasis]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Established by the Treaty of Bern of 1874, the [Universal Postal Union - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Postal_Union#General_Postal_Union) is the bases of the **international postage agreements** meantioned in your quote.